# xdotool error: xdotool: Unknown command: window

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, xdotool

I am using xdotool to run some automation on a firefox browser but i get an error when run
xdotool: Unknown command: window

Any idea what i am entering in incorrectly please?

here is my xdotool code block

```
sleep 10  # Ensure this has started before moving on, waiting for loading the Chime web app

id=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --name Firefox)
xdotool window focus --sync $id
xdotool key Return #Select yes for the pop-up window of "Would you like to open this link with Chime app?" 
sleep 3
xdotool key Escape #Close the pop-up window
sleep 3
xdotool type broadcast #Type "broadcast" on the name input field 
sleep 3
xdotool key Tab #Move to "join the meeting" button
sleep 3
xdotool key Return #Click "join the meeting" button
sleep 3
xdotool key Return #Close the pop-up window once again
sleep 3 
xdotool key Escape #Close the pop-up window once again
sleep 3
xdotool key Return #Click "Use system audio" setting
sleep 3
xdotool key Escape #Close warning message
sleep 3
```

i have tried the above thank you